# How to define vehicle maximum speed in Sumo using jtrrouter

Tags: sumo

I generated vehicles using jtrrouter in Sumo by turning probability. I first define a vehicle flow and turning probability as below:

```
<routes>
  <flow id="0" from="e1" begin="0" end="1200" number="180"/>
  <flow id="1" from="e3" begin="0" end="1200" number="180"/>
  <flow id="3" from="e5" begin="0" end="1200" number="180"/>
  <flow id="4" from="e7" begin="0" end="1200" number="180"/>
</routes>

<turns>
    <interval begin="0" end="1200">
        <fromEdge id="e3">
            <toEdge id="e6" probability="0.2"/>
            <toEdge id="e8" probability="0.4"/>
            <toEdge id="e2" probability="0.4"/>
        </fromEdge>

        <fromEdge id="e1">
            <toEdge id="e4" probability="0.3"/>
            <toEdge id="e6" probability="0.2"/>
            <toEdge id="e8" probability="0.5"/>
        </fromEdge>

        <fromEdge id="e7">
            <toEdge id="e2" probability="0.28"/>
            <toEdge id="e4" probability="0.55"/>
            <toEdge id="e6" probability="0.17"/>
        </fromEdge>

        <fromEdge id="e5">
            <toEdge id="e8" probability="0.06"/>
            <toEdge id="e2" probability="0.69"/>
            <toEdge id="e4" probability="0.25"/>
        </fromEdge>


    </interval>
</turns>
```

Then it will generate s sequence of vehicles like this:

```
<routes>
    <vehicle id="0.0" depart="0.00" departSpeed="10">
        <route edges="e1 e8"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="1.0" depart="0.00" departSpeed="10">
        <route edges="e3 e8"/>
    </vehicle>
    <vehicle id="3.0" depart="0.00" departSpeed="10">
        <route edges="e5 e2"/>
    </vehicle>
    .
    .
    .
<routes>
```

But what should we do if we want to define the max speed for such vehicles using this method? Where do we need to include the speed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Max speed is a property of vehicle type definition `vType`. I suggest you create a file `my_vType_definition.add.xml` where you create `vType` with `maxSpeed`. It will look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<additional xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/additional_file.xsd">
    <vType id="my_vtype"  vClass="passenger" carFollowModel="IDM" maxSpeed="13.9" speedDev="0.1">
    <!-- maxSpeed is in m/s so 13.9 ~= 50 km/h -->
    </vType>
</additional>
```

Then your `flow` definitions can include the vehicle type like this:

```xml
<routes>
  <flow id="0" type="my_vType" from="e1" begin="0" end="1200" number="180"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</routes>
```

The file with new `vType` needs to be added to your config file (sumocfg) as additional file. It might be necessary to add it also to `jtrouter` with `-d <FILE>` or `--additional-files <FILE>` params.

Then `jtrrouter` should generate vehicles with maximum speed.